# How to read/write from/to a drive directly using Win32 API

Tags: java, c, winapi, volume, partition

Without having to write a low-level Windows driver, but still using either Java or some C-based API, is it possible to read/write from/to a raw, unpartitioned drive... one that has got no file-system on it?

A short sample program would help. If not, at least knowing what standard Windows/Java (or, 3rd Party) API I could use in userspace (without having to write a device driver) would help.

Comment: Possibly. Either the device could be completely unpartitioned. Or, it may have a partition or two with no well-known file-system on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to access a raw disk using the [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  function by passing

```
 "\\.\PhysicalDriveX"
```

as name.

Where `X` is a `0`-based index counting the drives.

Comment: Thanks. Also, any way to enumerate my "device of interest", say by its serial number, manufacturer/vendor, etc?

Comment: @Harry: As this strongly depends on the hardware in use, I **suppose** you won't get around "asking" the driver. You might like to google for "harddisk meta data winapi" or something alike.

Comment: Good enough pointer. Thanks, alk.

Comment: @Harry: Great! :-) So, let's clean up those now meaningless comments, ok?